# How Replace Xaml Text with Text based on MarkUp Extensions automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

We have some translation mark up extension which looks like this:

```
TextBlock Text="{l:Translate 'My string'}"
```

and we want (because we could use some other tool for xaml translation) to replace text tags inside of all project xamls automatically.

Is there any way to find out all nodes or attributes with regex or with xml reader/write to implement this case?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want, but if its changing multiple TextBlock element text at once, you should consider binding the elements to a common property and modifying the property as needed.

Comment: We want replace such elements as Text="" automatically within xaml file for example from visual studio addin.

Comment: Sorry. Wish i could help, but I dont think i've ever needed to to anything like that before (besides ctrl+r).

Comment: it wouldn't be too hard to write a program that simply goes through every xaml single file in your project folder and replace the strings, they are just text after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used regular expressions which is not the best way but we can leave with it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `XAML` meets the standard `XML`, but to work with it, you need external libraries. As an example: `Microsoft XAML Toolkit CTP` ([download](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4720)). Simple example, which displays a list of items:

```
// Previously adding the library
using Microsoft.Xaml.Tools.XamlDom;

XamlDomObject rootObject = XamlDomServices.Load("MainWindow.xaml");

foreach (XamlDomObject domObject in rootObject.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    MessageBox.Show(domObject.Type.ToString());
}
```

Set `Background` on every `Control` in your document:

```
XamlDomObject rootObject = XamlDomServices.Load("MainWindow.xaml");
    foreach (XamlDomObject objectNode in
        from control in rootObject.DescendantsAndSelf(typeof(Control))
        where !control.HasMember("Background")
        select control)
{
    objectNode.SetMemberValue("Background", "Red");
}

XamlDomServices.Save(rootObject, "NewFile.xaml");
```

For replace value of `Text` property, I use example:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XamlDomObject rootObject = XamlDomServices.Load("MainWindow.xaml");

    foreach (XamlDomObject objectNode in
            from control in rootObject.DescendantsAndSelf(typeof(TextBlock))
            where control.HasMember("Text")
            select control)
    {
            objectNode.SetMemberValue("Text", "MyInsertedText");
    }

    XamlDomServices.Save(rootObject, "NewFile.xaml");
}
```

File `Input`:

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLdom.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="SomeText" Width="100" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

File `Output`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window xml:base="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Kanc/мои документы/visual studio 2010/Projects/XAMLdom/XAMLdom/bin/Debug/MainWindow.xaml" x:Class="XAMLdom.MainWindow" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="MyInsertedText" Width="100" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is it possible also to set Content of XAML Element? For example <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>?

Comment: Yes you can. But probably depends on the type of `Control`. Please see my edit, where I used `<TextBlock Text="SomeText /">`. For more detailed information, refer to the documentation.

Comment: I would like to know how content could be changed with this framework

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, maybe you're his mark as an answer? :)